# ROBLOX Studio ScreenGui score display

Tags: roblox

How do I make a `TextLabel`'s text update to a variable?

[image: screen shot 1]

I have tried setting the text to `"score: ", _G.score`

but it won't update with the variable, and yes I do set the text after the variable has updated.

Code:

```
script.Parent.mouseClick:connect(function()
   _G.score = _G.score + 1
   game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.TextLabel.Text = _G.score
end)
```

Comment: Is this code located in a `Script` or a `LocalScript`?

Comment: a normal `Script`

Comment: If you ever put a script inside of a GUI, it is supposed to be in a `LocalScript`. Since each player's GUI is unique to them (if I click a button, it should not make a change in *your* GUI), it must be handled by each player's computer. `Script`s are run by the server, whereas `LocalScript`s are run by each player's computer locally. I must admit, however, that I'm not sure if this is a mere formality or if this is actually important; it's been quite a while since I learned this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`game.StarterGui` is actually a template GUI, and every time a player joins the game, a **copy** of it is made and given to the new player. Thus, if you try to modify it, you will not be actually modifying the copies of it that were given to all the players.

There are two solutions to this problem:

1. **Only use relative paths**—that being, only use paths to GUI objects that begin with "`script.`" just like you said `script.Parent.mouseClick:connect(…)`.
2. **Iterate through all the copies that have been given out to the players.** This can be found under each `Player` object's `.PlayerGui`.

You should almost never do the latter. Here's how you can decide:

If you have code that is found *within* the `StarterGui` (rather than in the Workspace or something), then you should use the former. This is because when the `StarterGui` gets copied into a new player's GUI (called a `PlayerGui`), that script will get copied along with it since it was inside of the `StarterGui`. Thus, a relative path like `script.Parent.Something.SomethingElse.Text = "hi"` will be valid; it will affect *that* `PlayerGui`.

If you have some code that is **not** within the `StarterGui` (like if it's in the Workspace), then you must use the latter. This is because such a script will not get copied into each player's `PlayerGui`. As a result, you must go through each player's `PlayerGui` in a for loop or something similar. This scenario is very rarely the case, and if it ever is, consider trying to make it not the case if possible because this is a very hairy situation to try to deal with; you have to account for special circumstances like the possibility that a player hasn't gotten a copy of the `StarterGui` yet.

Please let me know if this explanation was in any way confusing; I'll try my best to explain it better.

You can find some visuals to go along with this explanation and some further reading on the official ROBLOX Wiki's explanation of this topic here: ["Player vs. Starter GUIs"](https://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Player_vs._Starter_GUIs).